# Powershell script: How to find file based on partial user input and print?

Tags: powershell

I need a script that allow user to search a large folder for a specific `.pdf` file and the `Invoke-Item` cmdlet.  Problem is that the user won't know the exact file name, meaning he/she will know the first 5 digits but not the rest of the file name.

**Example: User knows the file starts with '12345' but the file will actually be '12345-H EXP'.**

Here is the script I have so far:

```
$eoRef = Read-Host -Prompt "EO Number?"

Get-ChildItem -Path '.\C:\Folder_file_example\EO_files\' 
    + *$eoRef* -Recurse | Invoke-Item
```

User will be prompted to enter EO Number. User enters '12345' and the file will actually be '12345-H EXP'

I end up with an error that the '*12345*'  argument can't be accepted.

Any ideas?

I'd greatly appreciate any feedback

Thanks
Matt

Comment: What do you intent to do if there is another file named `12345-G EXP` or more files with similar starting names?

Comment: These are engineers order references so that most likely won't happen. However I do need to find a way to create   If Then option incase the EO Number is entered in error or doest exist???

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path '.\C:\Folder_file_example\EO_files\' 
    -Include *$eoRef* -Recurse | Invoke-Item
```